# Retrieve and cache a result set into my Application

Tags: c#, entity-framework, fingerprint, digital-persona-sdk

I have a `byte[]` column in a table that has fingerprint data stored in it. I wish to query the rows from a table only once and store the record set in a variable or somewhere in my code, so that I don't have to query the database each and every time. The query will return thousands of rows.

This will fetch all the records for me:

```
var table = (from a in context.tblFingerprints
                              select new {a} ).ToList();
```

I tried declaring a variable in AppData class: `public List<object> TableData;`
Then tried to store the variable 'table' values to it.

```
Data.TableData = table;
```

The error remains:

> Cannot implicitly convert type `'System.Collections.Generic.List<<anonymous type: FingerprintTEST.tblFingerprint a>>'` to `'System.Collections.Generic.List<object>'`

This is how I wish to query the rows returned from the result for matching fingerprint:

```
foreach (var row in Data.TableData)
{
    Template tem = new Template();
    tem.DeSerialize(row.a.fingerTemplate);

    if (tem != null)
    {
        // Compare feature set with particular template.
        Verificator.Verify(features, tem, ref res);

        if (res.Verified)
        {...}
    }
}
```

Any ideas please?

Comment: What is the data type of `context.tblFingerprints`?

Comment: Databases are designed to be queried, have you run into a performance issue?

Comment: @MichaelRandall Well, as my database grows it takes much more time to retrieve and compare one fingerprint against thousands of records.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning these as new objects with `select new {a}`. If `context.tblFingerprints` is of type `TableData` you just need to `select a`

```
var table = (from a in context.tblFingerprints
                          select a).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

- You don't need the `select new { a }` (this is creating a new anonymous-type, with a single member for a whole record, which is silly.

  - You also don't need any Linq expression at all, just use `ToList()` on the `DbSet` directly.
- Store the result in a static variable.

```
class Something
{
    private static List<tblFingerprint> _fingerprints;

    public void Do()
    {
        DbContext context = ...

        if( _fingerprints is null )
        {
            _fingerprints = context.tblFingerprints.ToList();
        }

        // do stuff with `_fingerprints`
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "new {a}" and replace with just "a", and tell ToList that it's a list of objects.

```
var table = (from a in context.tblFingerprints
             select a).ToList<object>();
```